# How to get dashboard usage statistics for Report Builder reports?

Tags: reportbuilder, usage-statistics, powerbi-paginated-reports

I would like to get dashboard usage statistics on a Report Builder report published in the PBI cloud.  I don't see a link that provides this like Power BI does

I looked for a Usage Statistics link in the service (just like you can see for Power BI dashboards), but there is none for Report Builder reports